# How can I print arguments with spaces between, using the print() method?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

If I feed the Python 2.x interpreter with

```
    print 1, 2, 3
```

, it will output

```
    1 2 3
```

When I feed the 3.0 interpreter the same input, eclipse (PyDev) encounters an error; "Was expecting one of:  ..". However, it is able to run the code and give the same output.
Why do I get this error? Also, how can I print the same output with the print() method? I have tried

```
    print(1, 2, 3)
```

, but this outputs the tuple

```
    (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce; `print(1,2,3)` prints "1 2 3" on my Python 3. (Almost certainly you're not actually running a Python 3 interpreter; Python 2 will show the output you claim Python 3 does.)

Comment: the "PyDev- Interpreter/Grammar" settings has "Grammar Version" set to 3.0. Is this not sufficient?

Comment: @Skogen: What PyDev says is hardly relevant, it's what the Python interpreter says that is relevant. Check what sys.version is.

Comment: What does "However, it is able to run the code and give the same output. " mean? Either it works or you get an error. You can't have it be able to run the code and unable to run the code at the same time.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading sentence. It is probably not an actual error, but eclipse marks an occurrence of what it thinks is an error - it sets a red mark under the code, and when I hover the mouse over, it says "was expecting..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(1, 2, 3)
```

Works under Python 3. If you get a tuple then that's Python 2.

if you do

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Then it will work under Python 2 as well.

Comment: Then I have this question: how can I use Python 3 in PyDev when (project -> properties -> PyDev-Interpreter/Grammar -> grammar version 3.0) apparently is not working/sufficient?

Comment: @Skogen: You have to select which python interpreter to use. That must be a part of the PyDev documentation, it is a very basic feature. (In fact, googling for pydev python version will take you directly to the answer)